# Assign Entity Framework Navigation Property without Query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working with an asp MVC5 app with entity framework 6 and want to create an object that has a navigation property like so:

```
public class widget
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

where the property `Category` is another entity in the database model. When I implement the CRUD functionality, I create a view model like so:

```
public class EditWidgetViewModel
{
    public List<SelectListItem> Categories { get; set; }
    public int CategoryId { get; set; }
}
```

and the contents of the selectList goes to a dropdown in the html form. Next, the `CategoryId` gets posted back to the server when the user submits the form. From there, I am currently doing something like the following to save changes:

```
var dbWidget = new Widget
{
    Name = model.Name,
    Category = db.Categories.Find(CategoryId)
}

db.Widgets.Add(dbWidget);
db.SaveChanges();
```

So my question is the following: can I assign the category navigation property without doing another DB lookup with `db.Widgets.Find(WidgetId)` - I already know the id number that should go in the `Category_Category_Id` column in the Widgets table of the database without doing a lookup. Also, it seems like if you have something with five or so navigation properties that this would be a significant performance problem with a round trip for each of those.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  create a new entity with a constructor, assign it a proper id
then use dbContext's Entry().State like this:

```
Category category = new Category  { Id = CategoryId };
db.Entry(category).State = EntityState.Unchanged;

var dbWidget = new Widget
{
    Name = model.Name,
    Category = category
}

db.Widgets.Add(dbWidget);
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, this works great! Just out of curiosity, lets say that I assign an incorrect id (i.e. it doesn't exist) - does this throw an error?

Comment: Depends on weather or not you have a foreign key relationship defined in the database.
All this code does is set the CategoryId to the Id of a category that you instantiate in code. If there is a Foreign Key constraint in database - SaveChanges - will throw.